# Como montar um RestRequest com x-www-form-urlencoded no RestSharp C#

Tags: c#, restsharp

Sei fazer requisição utilizando o RestSharp quando o `content-type = application/json`, agora preciso fazer uma requisição `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mas não consigo encontrar o modo correto de fazer isso, segue o um exemplo de como eu monto a requisição`application/json`:

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Resource = "/search";
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { bucketId = bucketID, startFileName = fileName, maxFileCount = maxFileCount }), ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", authorize_account.authorizationToken);
```

A forma como eu passo o body quando se trata de JSON é essa, como faço quando se trata de x-www-form-urlencoded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É parecido.

Só precisa mudar o *header*  e adicionar cada par chave-valor com o método `AddParameter`.

```
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//...

request.AddParameter("nome", "valor");
request.AddParameter("1_nome", "1_valor");
```

Comment: Funcionou ! Obrigado, aliás consegui descobrir um outro modo de fazer isso, mas o seu é mais legível.

Comment: Funcionou, só tive que mudar o contentType para esse: request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira que eu descobri fora a resposta do @LINQ é adicionar a url no parâmetro `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` escrevendo-a de forma manual :

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.Resource = "/search";
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Version", "v1.0");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $"api_key={api.api_key}&access_key={api.access_key}&timestamp={api.timestamp}&nonce={api.nonce}&algo=sha1&q=woman&lang=en&page=0&limit=100", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

A diferença é a legibilidade, achei melhor utilizar o do @LINQ mesmo.

Comment: É porque esse é o resultado final da abordagem do LINQ

Comment: Yep :P de qualquer forma quis postar pois é uma outra solução né ?